# MKDOCS - How to enable hyperlinks based on keywords found in the content?

Tags: plugins, mkdocs

I am using [MkDocs](http://www.mkdocs.org), question I have is - I understand that within the documentation files I can say: 
`[My Link Name](My link URL)`

But it's such a hustle when I want to change up my navigation or change up my keywords.

Can anyone suggest a plugin - At the point of building the documentation, automatically find keywords that would match up with keywords within the `mkdocs.yml`file and create a hyperlink to them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing, seems to be a primitive form of [interwiki links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interwiki_links). There is a plugin that you could use: [markdown extra](https://github.com/rosscdh/mkdocs-markdownextradata-plugin).

You could define your wikilinks, or wikilinks components in your `mkdocs.yaml`file, like so, e.g.:

```
extra:
  interwiki:
    stackoverflow: stackoverflow.com/questions/
    google: https://www.google.com/search?q=
```

Then you would use the "mustache" notation:

```
Please refer to the [question on StackOverflow]({{ interwiki.stackoverflow }}48173267)
```

Which would be equivalent to:

```
Please refer to the [question on StackOverflow](stackoverflow.com/questions/48173267)
```

I haven't tried it, but that would be the gist. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if all you want is to make links within a single web domain, MkDocs supports the standards [extensions](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/) of python-markdown, hence also [WikiLinks](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/wikilinks/).

The syntax in the md file is a "double bracket":

```
Link to this [[full description]]
```

Which would become => `https://your.website.com/foo/bar/full_description.html`

According to the documentation, what you would have to do, is to specify in your mkdocs.yml file:

```
markdown_extensions:
    - wikilinks:
      - base_url: https://your.website.com/foo/bar/
      - end_url: .html
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it yet, so anyone who has is welcome to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to add wikilinks to mkdocs by using the [mkdocs-ezlinks-plugin](https://pypi.org/project/mkdocs-ezlinks-plugin/).

Install the plugin:

```sh
pip3 install mkdocs-ezlinks-plugin
```

> note that your OS may prefer `pip` instead of `pip3`

Add the following to `mkdocs.yml`:

```yaml
plugins:
  - search
  - ezlinks:
      wikilinks: true
```

The plugin does some really nice translation of links and searches the document tree for matching titles.

| Link | Translation |
| --- | --- |
| `[[Page Name]]` | `[Page Name](../folder2/page-name.md)` |
| `![[Puppy]]` | `![Puppy](../images/puppy.png)` |
| `[[Page Name|Link Text]]` | `[Link Text](../folder2/page-name.md)` |
| `[[Page Name#Section Heading|Link Text]]` | `[Link Text](../folder2/page-name.md#section-heading)` |